# Convert text to always be uppercase in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to make my input text always be uppercase in a blazor input text field. I tried creating a custom InputText like the below but it doesn't update the binding (appears as uppercase but doesn't bind as such). What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way?

```
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(
        this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value.ToUpper(), CurrentValueAsString.ToUpper())" />
```

Comment: Perhaps set the server-side property `set` function toUpper() when setting the value.

Comment: Is the user allowed to type lowercase letters, and you will transform it to upper case, or are you restricting input to ONLY uppercase letters? If you're doing the transformation, are you doing it on every character typed or after the element leaves focus?

Comment: @gunr2171 either one works fine... the idea is that when they submit the form they all must be uppercase. ideally it would be while typing or prevent lowercase input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old reference to the input which was causing the error. There was a bug in the code though (if the input was null). The corrected version can be seen here:

```
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(
        this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value?.ToUpper(), CurrentValueAsString?.ToUpper())" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplicity works for me.

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" @bind=CurrentValueAsString />
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the cursor moves to the end

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was easier than all the answers: it can be solved using CSS `text-transform: uppercase;`. This is all you needed and it doesn't take any processing power because it's included in the browser's engine.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and (in my opinion) UX reasons, let's assume that the user is allowed to type lowercase letters, but the application will ToUpper the input after they leave that field.

First, make a new component so we can reuse the logic. I called mine `UppercaseTextInput.razor`

```
<input value="@UserInput" 
       @onchange="async e => await OnChange(e)" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string UserInput { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> UserInputChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var upperCase = (e.Value as string).ToUpperInvariant();
        await UserInputChanged.InvokeAsync(upperCase);
    }
}
```

The private method `OnChange` gets called whenever the input loses focus. Change `@onchange` to `@oninput` to make this happen every keystroke.

Now you can use this component in another page or component. For example, in the index page:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<UppercaseTextInput @bind-UserInput="UserInput" />
<p>You typed: @UserInput</p>

@code {
    public string UserInput { get; set; } = "Initial";
}
```

In this example, I have "Initial" as the starting text, which will be printed inside the text box. As soon as you *leave* the element, the text inside will be transformed to be uppercase.

The benefit of using a component is that you can do a standard `@bind-` with your properties.

Comment: I originally did this but the cursor always jumps to end when editing so it was a no go

Comment: @Dan that's if you use `@oninput` so that it fires every keystroke. `@onchange` will occur when the element's focus is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/).
I scratched my head for a while why the heck adding

```
Style="text-transform: uppercase;"
```

to `<MudInput>` is not working, even with `!important` attribute the default user agent style (`text-transform: none;`) was applied.
C# or JS seemed overkill for the task in my opinion.
What finally worked for me was adding

```
 input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

to the **site's CSS sheet** (index.css in my case).
This eventually overwritten the default user agent style.